# 'whois' responds with "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function"

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

So I'm kinda new to coding with javascript. I thought a good way to get myself started was to code a Discord bot. however, when I try and run the whois command, the terminal responds with

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.members.get is not a function"

```js
module.exports = {
    getMember: function(message, toFind = '') {
        toFind = toFind.toLowerCase();

        let target = message.guild.members.get(toFind); //<- Not a function?

        if (!target && message.mentions.members)
            target = message.mentions.members.first();

        if (!target && toFind) {
            target = message.guild.members.find(member => {
                return member.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(toFind) ||
                member.user.tag.toLowerCase().includes(toFind)
            });
        }

        if (!target) 
            target = message.member;

        return target;
    },

    formatDate: function(date) {
        return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put a debugger on that line so you can see what values are available and learn more about that `members` property. Checkout debugging in VSCode [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_start-debugging).

Comment: What makes you think the [`.get()` method exists?](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 1):

In v12, [managers were introduced](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache) so `message.guild.members` is a [`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager), not a collection. To access the collection use `message.guild.members.cache` (i.e. `message.guild.members.cache.get(toFind)`).