# How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I upgraded to Discord.js v12, but it broke my existing v11 code. Here are some examples of things that cause errors:

```js
// TypeError: client.users.get is not a function
const user = client.users.get('123456789012345678')

// TypeError: message.guild.roles.find is not a function
const role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Admin')

// TypeError: message.member.addRole is not a function
await message.member.addRole(role)

// TypeError: message.guild.createChannel is not a function
await message.guild.createChannel('welcome')

// TypeError: message.channel.fetchMessages is not a function
const messages = await message.channel.fetchMessages()

const {RichEmbed} = require('discord.js')
// TypeError: RichEmbed is not a constructor
const embed = new RichEmbed()

const connection = await message.channel.join()
// TypeError: connection.playFile is not a function
const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./music.mp3')
```

How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 and fix these errors? Where can I see the breaking changes v12 introduced?

Comment: To whoever voted to close this as ‘needs more focus’: this question was the result of [this meta discussion](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401142/8289918) about having a canonical question that would answer issues relating to upgrading to Discord.js v12, most notably the introduction of managers. There were [*a lot*](/questions/linked/63911361) of questions relating to the upgrade that have been marked as duplicates of this question. I don’t believe this question is too broad; if this was split up into multiple questions it would have the same information (read the migration guide and the docs).

Comment: If you still believe this question is too broad, feel free to open a discussion on meta, but at this stage I don’t think any action is needed on this question especially considering that Discord.js v13 has been released.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are some of the most common breaking changes introduced in Discord.js v12 that people run into.

## Managers

Properties such as `Client#users` and `Guild#roles` are now **managers**, instead of the cached `Collection` of items. To access this collection, use the [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BaseManager?scrollTo=cache) property:

```js
const user = client.users.cache.get('123456789012345678')
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Admin')
```

In addition, methods such as `GuildMember#addRole`, `Guild#createChannel`, and `TextBasedChannel#fetchMessages` have moved to the respective managers:

```js
await message.member.roles.add(role)
await message.guild.channels.create('welcome')
const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch()
```

## `Collection`

The [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) class (e.g. `client.users.cache`, `guild.roles.cache`, `guild.channels.cache`) now only accepts **functions**, not property keys and values, for `.find` and `.findKey`:

```js
// v11: collection.find('property', 'value')
collection.find(item => item.property === 'value')
```

`.exists`, `.deleteAll`, `.filterArray`, `.findAll` have also been removed:

```js
// v11: collection.exists('property', 'value')
collection.some(item => item.property === 'value')

// v11: collection.deleteAll()
Promise.all(collection.map(item => item.delete()))

// v11: collection.filterArray(fn)
collection.filter(fn).array()

// v11: collection.findAll('property', value')
collection.filter(item => item.property === 'value').array()
```

`.tap` now runs a function on the collection instead of every item in the collection:

```js
// v11: collection.tap(item => console.log(item))
collection.each(item => console.log(item))

// New .tap behaviour:
collection.tap(coll => console.log(`${coll.size} items`))
```

## `RichEmbed`/`MessageEmbed`

The `RichEmbed` class has been removed; use the **[`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)** class instead which is now used for all embeds (instead of just received embeds).

```js
const {MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js')
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
```

The `addBlankField` method has also been removed. This method simply added a field with a zero-width space (`\u200B`) as the name and value, so to add a blank field do this:

```js
embed.addField('\u200B', '\u200B')
```

## Voice

All of the `VoiceConnection`/`VoiceBroadcast#play***` methods have been unified under a single **[`play`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PlayInterface?scrollTo=play)** method:

```js
const dispatcher = connection.play('./music.mp3')
```

`Client#createVoiceBroadcast` has been moved to the [`ClientVoiceManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientVoiceManager?scrollTo=createBroadcast):

```js
const broadcast = client.voice.createVoiceBroadcast()
```

Additionally, `StreamDispatcher` extends Node.js' [`stream.Writable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable), so use `dispatcher.destroy()` instead of `dispatcher.end()`. The `end` event has been removed in favour of the native `finish` event.

## Image URLs

Properties such as `User#displayAvatarURL` and `Guild#iconURL` are now **methods**:

```js
const avatar = user.displayAvatarURL()
const icon = mesage.guild.iconURL()
```

You can also pass an [`ImageURLOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ImageURLOptions) to customise things like format and size.

## More information

To find out more about the v12 breaking changes, take a look at [the updating guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) and the [changelog](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/12.0.0). The [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) is also a good resource for finding a particular method/property.