# Discord.js Role Reactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

> TypeError: reaction.message.guild.roles.cache is not a function.

I don't understand what's wrong in my code below:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
 if (user.bot) return;

 var roleName = reaction.emoji.name;
 console.log(roleName);
 var role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache(
  (role) => role.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase()
 );
 var member = reaction.message.guild.members.find(
  (member) => member.id === user.id
 );

 if (member.roles.has(role.id)) {
  member
   .removeRole(role.id)
   .then((member) => {
    console.log(
     'Removed' + member.user.username + ' from the ' + role.name + ' role.'
    );
   })
   .catch((err) => console.error);
 } else {
  member
   .addRole(role.id)
   .then((member) => {
    console.log(
     'Added ' + member.user.username + ' to the ' + role.name + ' role.'
    );
   })
   .catch((err) => console.error);
 }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean `roles.find()`? I'm not sure what your trying to do.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing either. I'm just trying to add a role based on clicking on a reaction based on the user's input

Comment: and yes, roles.find() but it's just giving me the same error. TypeError: reaction.message.guild.roles.find is not a function

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Version: 12.3.1

Comment: If you need, I could send the rest of the code for you to see what's wrong

Comment: Oh, that's why. Almost all of your functions stopped working in v12. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to react to uncached messages you need to add partials.

You can find more information here: [Partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials)

I would recommend asking the guys over on [Discord.js](https://discord.com/invite/bRCvFy9)