# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined guild.roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make a very simple bot that if a member sends 'ping' , then the bot will send the number of people that have the role. But, it's giving me the error there.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

```js
client.on('message', async(msg) => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    let guild = await msg.guild.members.fetch();
    let roleID = '755766619229388800';
    let memberCount = guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size;
    msg.channel.send(memberCount + " members have this role!");
    console.log(memberCount)
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});
```

Please tell me what to change and explain to me the reason why the change should be made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of Discord.js, you can no longer use `get()` right off of roles. Also, I don't understanding why you are fetching members and assigning it as guild? You can access the guild right from `msg.guild`. With this in mind, you will need to instead use `msg.guild.roles.cache.get(roleId).members.size`

See the [Updating from v11 to v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) page to see the difference between versions