# Showing all people having a role in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command that can show the people having a role. Here is my code:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content == `+dump admin`) {
        const ListEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Users with the admin role:')
            .setDescription(message.guild.roles.get('741231292544188439').members.map(m=>m.user.tag).join('\n'));
        message.channel.send(ListEmbed);                    
    }
});
```

This code  gives me this error:

```
TypeError: message.guild.roles.get is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/MutedPinkBlogclient/index.js:244:49)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/MutedPinkBlogclient/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/MutedPinkBlogclient/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/MutedPinkBlogclient/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/MutedPinkBlogclient/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/MutedPinkBlogclient/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/MutedPinkBlogclient/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
```

Also this command gives me members for only specific roles only.. Anyway I can it can show for the role names I type or mention. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure discord js has a get method??? I couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: You should be looking in the [`Collection` docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/general/welcome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `cache` property in `discord.js` v12+

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.get(...)
```

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11?r=SearchResult)