# Is it possible to send a message to every guild my bot is in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have tried every tutorial but they don't work, here is my current code:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}globalannounce`)) {
        var msg = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
        var guildList = bot.guilds.array;
        try {
            let messageToSend = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Hello, you don't see me messaging in your server often...")
                .setDescription(`I have just flown in to tell you that my developers have something to say: \n ${msg}`)
            guildList.array.forEach(channel => {
                if (channel.type === 'text') channel.send(messageToSend).catch(console.error)
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
});
```

It will not work and the error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.js v12.x` uses [`Managers`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BaseManager), so you'll have to go through the [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache) property to get a list of guilds. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.8263) for more information.

Also, `GuildList.forEach()` would iterate a function throughout all *`Guilds`* in the collection, not all the channels. You can use the [`Channel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type) property and [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) to find the first text channel available.

```js
var guildList = bot.guilds.cache; // go through the cache property
try {
 let messageToSend = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Hello, you don't see me messaging in your server often...")
  .setDescription(
   `I have just flown in to tell you that my developers have something to say: \n ${msg}`
  );
 guildList.forEach((guild) => {
  const channel = guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.type === 'text') // try to find the channel
  if (!channel) return; // if it couldn't find a text channel, skip this guild
  channel.send(messageToSend); // otherwise, send the message
 });
} catch (err) {
 console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you're using discord.js v12

You have the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined`. This means that bot.guilds is equal to `undefined`. So the problem is here :

```js
        var guildList = bot.guilds.array;
```

You'll have to replace it with

```js
var guildList = bot.guilds.cache
```

So your entire code would look like this :

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}globalannounce`)) {
        var msg = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
        var guildList = bot.guilds.cache
        try {
            let messageToSend = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Hello, you don't see me messaging in your server often...")
                .setDescription(`I have just flown in to tell you that my developers have something to say: \n ${msg}`)
            guildList.forEach(guild =>{
guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.type === 'text').send(messageToSend)
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
});
```