# This addRole command is not working with no error on the console in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make a role command but the command just doesn't work, no error in the console, nothing.

Here is the command. This is on discord.js v12.

```js
client.on('message', function(message) {

    let member = message.mentions.members.first();

    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("my role id");


    if (message.content.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'test') {
        member.addRole(role).catch(console.error);
    }
})
```

sebasaez from the future here, the problem was that the function shoul be

```
clien.on('message', message =>{
//code
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 0):

`member.addRole` is not a function on v12, make sure this code runs by console logging anything, it should at least give you an error saying that it's not a function, you can add a role using `member.roles.add`, [link to documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add)

Comment: `member.roles.cache.add`

Comment: `member.roles.add` should work according to the docs, check your console and post any error you are getting, also log anything to make sure the code runs