# Discord.Js add role

Tags: discord.js, roles

I want to do a mute command, but when I do the command, the console output is `(node:67916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: msg.guild.roles.get is not a function`
Any ideas how i can fix that?

Comment: can you please share the code you used.

Comment: Assuming you're using v12.x, make sure to use the cache. `msg.guild.roles.cache.get()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, msg.guild.roles.get is not a function. Its quite hard to answer a question without seeing the code, you should always share your code, but the correct way to find and add a role is the following:

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
if(!member) member = message.author;
member.roles.add(role);
```

Since the update to V12, it is important that when trying to get roles, members or guilds you must include the .cache bit.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, i tried your code, but now I get another error. `(node:3584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: message is not defined`

Comment: @dxkyy that code was designed to go in a client.on("message" => message, but if you're not doing that, it wont be defined. Could you send the section of your current code?

Comment: Thats exactly why we need your code to answer your question @dxkyy

Comment: It's because they used `msg` as the parameter name instead of `message`

Comment: @dxkyy everywhere in that code where I put `message`, change that to `msg` and it should work. Thanks Lioness100 for pointing that out!

Comment: this is my code:     `if(command === 'mute') {
        const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted');
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        if(!member) member = message.author;
        member.roles.add(role);
    }`
Sorry for answering so late