# Error Changing @everyone Permissions Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, while making my DiscordJS bot I encountered yet another problem. I'm trying to make a lock channel function which prevents users from sending messages in that channel by changing permissions of @everyone. When you give the command, you mention the channel, so like this `!lockchannel #general`. But this yields an error: `chan.updateOverwrite is not a function`. Code is below:

```
//...
// msg is the message object
if (msg.mentions.channels.first()) {
  const chan = msg.mentions.channels.first()
  const role = chan.guild.roles.find('name', 'everyone');
  chan.updateOverwrite(role, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
} else {
  msg.reply("You didn't mention a channel")
}
//...
```

I'm using the latest version of Discord JS (12.4.0)
How can I fix this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you're using 12.4, `find('name', 'everyone')` is outdated. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11?r=SearchResults)

Comment: Oh wow thanks that seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//...
// msg is the message object
if (msg.mentions.channels.first()) {
  const chan = msg.mentions.channels.first()
  chan.updateOverwrite(msg.guild.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
} else {
  msg.reply("You didn't mention a channel")
}
//...
```

to update the perms of everyone just use the guild's id

Answer (score 0):

You just need
`message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: false })` Replace message.channel from defined channel and boom you're done!