# Why does my discord bot not add roles properly?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot that would add a role that is in the server when a person types !join choiceOutOfVariousRoles. I am currently using discord version 12. My error message is:

```
fn = fn.bind(thisArg);
```

Although trying various techniques I could not get the code to work.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client= new Discord.Client();
const token = process.env.DISCORD_BOT_SECRET




client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("I'm in");
    console.log(client.user.username);
});


client.on('message', msg  => {  
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!join"))
    {
        var args = msg.content.toLowerCase().split(" ")
        console.log(args)
        if (args[1] === 'sullen') 
        {
            msg.channel.send('You have successfully joined Sullen!')
            const sullenRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find('name','Sullen')
            msg.member.addRole(role.id)
            
        }
        
    }
});



client.login(token)
```

**EDIT:   Fixed what everyone was saying and all I need to do now Is update the permissions, (my friend has to do that because its not my bot) and I should be all good. Thanks everyone! :D

Comment: The first thing wrong with your code is that you're [mixing v11 and v12 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11?r=SearchResults&s=1|37.9350)

Comment: May you please elaborate?

Comment: you can only use `cache` in v12 and `addRole` is v11 syntax. What version do you have?

Comment: Right now I am using version 12.4.1.

Comment: Also you're using the wrong syntax for `Collection.prototype.find()`. Please check the page I linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

discord.js introduces breaking changes very frequently, and v12 is no exception. You need to make sure you find up-to-date code otherwise it won't work. `GuildMember#addRole` was moved to [`GuildMemberRoleManager#add`](https://discord.js.org#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager), which means you must use `msg.member.roles.add(sullenRole)`.