# My bot says 'invalid user' in discord chat whenever i try and use my purge command no error msgs in cmd or terminal

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a purge command, below is the code I have tried.

```js
 if(command === "purge") {

    const deleteCount = parseInt(args[0], 10);
    
 
    if(!deleteCount || deleteCount < 2 || deleteCount > 100)
      return message.reply("Please provide a number between 2 and 100 for the number of messages to delete");
    

    const fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: deleteCount});
    message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
      .catch(error => message.reply(`Couldn't delete messages because of: ${error}`));
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you using v12?

Comment: yes i am.......

Comment: i should switch to v11?

Comment: No, you should just update your code.

Comment: how do i update my code?

Comment: `if(bot.guilds.cache.get(guildID)!=undefined){thingsHere}` i think

Comment: @asy596 check [the post I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES"))
    return message.channel.send("**YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMS TO USE THIS!**");
  if (!args[1])
    return message.channel.send(
      "ERROR: You are missing an argument. Please declare the integer. `/purge <AMOUNT>`"
    );
  if (isNaN(args[1]))
    return message.channel.send(
      "ERROR: That is not a valid number to purge!"
    );
  message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);


  let clear = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .addField("Successfully purged", " **" + args[1] + " messages!**");

  message.channel.send(clear).then(r => r.delete({ timeout: 2000 }));
```

Also you do not need

> if(!deleteCount || deleteCount < 2 || deleteCount > 100)

because Discord API already does not allow bots to delete 100 or more messages. So you do not need to do anything with that.

Comment: Actually, OP does need that to handle potential errors.

Comment: True, but this command works fine for me.

Comment: True, but it doesn't actually solve the OPs problem. You just gave them completely new code as opposed to telling them why the error occurred.