# Discord.js: How to check is a human administrator?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Until version Discord.Js 12, my user verification function was like this in the form:

```
if (!discord.guilds.get(guilds_id).member(user_id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return `you are not an admin!`
```

Now from version Discord.Js 12. She stopped working for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has now been changed to `member.permissions.has("PERMISSION HERE")`

so it would be

```
if (!discord.guilds.get(guilds_id).member(user_id).permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))
```

Comment: (node:30232) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'permissions' of nul

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js v12 now uses cache,
the new way of checking if a user has administrator permission is:

assumung you set your Discord.Client as the variable "discord" (let discord = `new Discord.Client`)

```
let guild = discord.guilds.cache.get(guilds.id)
let member = guild.members.cache.get(member.id)
if (!member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You are not an admin!")
```

searching for members might also give a few errors if you haven't yet turned on Server Member Gateway Intents, turn them on from the discord developer portal, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d91oc.png)

Comment: In this code: let member = guild.members.cache.get(member.id), i got this result: undefined

Comment: is member.id a valid user id from the guild

Comment: Even in this form, "let member" does not work.
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('762247173735317526')
let member = guild.members.cache.get('553633091403382794')

Comment: have you verified if the member id your using is valid? 
Go to the guild 762247173735317526, and then try typing `<@553633091403382794>`, if it shows the member, then there may be an error with your bot not having server member gateway intents, as i explained in the answer