# Doesn't create the voice channel with no error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to build a bot with the discord.js library in node.js that will create a new voice channel in a certain category when a user joins a certain channel. After the creation of the channel, I want the bot to then move the user to the new channel!

I am trying the following code:

```js
var temporary = [];

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldMember, newMember) => {
 const mainCatagory = '815281015207624704';
 const mainChannel = '814938402137833484';

 if (newMember.voiceChannelID == mainChannel) {
  await newMember.guild
   .createChannel(` ┋ Support Room`, { type: 'voice', parent: mainCatagory })
   .then(async (channel) => {
    temporary.push({ newID: channel.id, guild: newMember.guild.id });
    await newMember.setVoiceChannel(channel.id);
   });
 }

 if (temporary.length >= 0)
  for (let i = 0; i < temporary.length; i++) {
   let ch = client.guilds
    .find((x) => x.id === temporary[i].guild)
    .channels.find((x) => x.id === temporary[i].newID);

   if (ch.members.size <= 0) {
    await ch.delete();

    return temporary.splice(i, 1);
   }
  }
});
```

The code comes with no error but doesn't create the voice channel!

Comment: What discord.js version are you using?

Comment: I am using the version v12+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using discord.js v12, but your code is made for v11.

- [`Client#voiceStateUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=e-voiceStateUpdate) now passes [`VoiceStates`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState) as parameters, not [`GuildMembers`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember). You should rename `newMember` and `oldMember` to `newState` and `oldState` respectively.
- [`GuildMember#voiceChannelID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voiceChannelID) is a deprecated property, which is why you don't get any errors. Your code never actually gets past the if statement. It has turned into [`GuildMember#voice#channelID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.1/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channelID) (`newState.channelID`).
- [`Guild#createChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel) is also deprecated, being replaced with [`Guild#channels#create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create). The function still looks and acts the same, so you only need to change the name (`newState.guild.channels.create`).
- [`GuildMember#setVoiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setVoiceChannel) has turned into [`GuildMember#voice#setChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setChannel) (`newState.setChannel`)
- [`Client#guilds#find`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) has turned into [`Client#guilds#cache#find`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) (`client.guilds.cache.find`)
- [`Guild#channels#find`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) has turned into [`Guild#channels#cache#find`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) (`client.cache.find(...).channels.cache.find`)

(As a side note, always use [`Collection#get`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) instead of [`Collection#find`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) when searching by IDs. `.find((value) => value.id === '...')` should always be converted to simply `.get('...')`. This also applies to switching [`Collection#some`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) with [`Collection#has`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get))

- [`Guild#members#size`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) has turned into [`Guild#members#cache#size`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) (`ch.members.cache.size`)

Every single one of these deprecations occurred as a result of discord.js switching to a Manager/caching system. For example, [`Client#guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) now returns a **[`GuildManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildManager)** instead of a collection.

[More information about switching from v11 to v12 (including Managers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Comment: thank you very much ! It was , like in my country says in free translate, in front of my eyes and I couldn't see it. I have got a problem that says that `newMember#voice#channelID` is undefined

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: I have got a problem that says that `newMember#voice#channelID` is undefined.

Comment: [`VoiceState#channelID`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channelID) will be undefined if the member is not in a voice channel.

Comment: I want to join the mainChannel and bot create new voice channel and move me in. When I join the mainChannel this error coming up. If I join any other voice channel comes with the same error!

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. Editing my answer now

Comment: thank you very much ! I appreciate your time and your help ! ALL THE BEST !