# Discord.js message.member.roles.has is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I try to run this code:

```js
if (message.member.roles.has('818770654580834314')) {
   message.channel.send('ok');
}
```

And I have this error:
`TypeError: message.member.roles.has is not a function`

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, the method has been changed to `message.member.roles.cache.has('818770654580834314')`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to mark it as correct (the green check) so that we both get reputation and the question is marked as solved :)

Comment: I know, but I have to wait 4 minutes :)