# Discord.js v12+ TypeError: member.roles.map is not a function

Tags: discord.js, typeerror

So I was using this to show all the roles on a user that leaves the server for logs and I believe map is no longer a function but I'm curious would `.name` also serve as a similarity to the map function?

```
bot.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
    if(!member.lastMessage) member.lastMessage = "N/A"
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === botconfig["channel_setup"].general_logs_channel);
                let leaveLog = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Red Cross Roleplay | Action Log")
                    .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                    .setDescription(`**Action:** Member Left`)
                    .addField('Member Left', `<@${member.user.id}> - Hash: ${member.user.tag} - ID: ${member.user.id}`)
                    .addField('Member Roles', member.roles.name(r => `${r}`).join(' '))
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter(botconfig["bot_setup"].copyright);
                    channel.send(leaveLog)
    });
```

would this still work?

```
.addField('Member Roles', member.roles.name(r => `${r}`).join(' '))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Comment: @Lioness100 I believe not. I'm just curious if `.map` has been changed to `.name` and if not what would `.map` have changed to?

Comment: It did not change at all. You are using outdated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying outdated code it seems. In the discord.js docs, you can see that [GuildMember.roles](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles) is an instance of [GuildMemberRoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager). You will have to use the [cache](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) property which returns a Collection which you can then use the `.map()` function on.

Here is how to implement it

```js
member.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`)
```

Comment: Yeah It was v11 to v12 I just thought they removed `.map()` Because I have seen stuff about that.

Comment: Please check mark this answer if it helped!

Comment: (hit the tick mark next to the upvote symbol)

Comment: @MrMythical I was planning on it but I had a timer :D